# Can multiple regression assess the impact of a recurring event?

Tags: multiple-regression

I’m trying to determine the impact of a recurring event on a local restaurant’s sales, and I have only a single year’s worth of data. Would it be possible to assess this with multiple regression? My thinking is that I could do the following:

•   Sum up the sales by hour for each day over the yearlong period.

•   Instead of doing a straight datetime like I would for a time series, I’d have the following to capture hourly, weekly and seasonal cycles:

```
   One field for hour of the day, 
   Fields for day of the week (transformed appropriately for multiple regression)
   Fields for month (transformed appropriately for MR)
```

•   I’d add a binary field called “holiday” that would be 1 during all holidays the restaurant was closed and 0 for all others.

•   I’d add a binary field called “event” that would be 1 during all hours in which the event was happening and 0 for all others.

•   I’d add a binary field called “pre_event” that would be 1 in the two hours before every event and 0 for all other hours.

•   I’d add a binary field called “post_event” that would be 1 in the two hours after every event and 0 for all other hour.

When this data was prepared, I’d then run the multiple regression and assess the statistical significance and the effect size of the event, pre-event and post-event variables.

Would this be a reasonable approach or would it be using a tool for which it isn’t intended?

Comment: Yes, that would work just fine.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the confirmation!